# How to show debug info on Kwin task switcher error?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, kwin

Recently I've installed [Present Windows Clone](https://store.kde.org/p/1112558/) tasks switcher on KDE store, but it won't work. Whenever I try to switch windows, it prints to notifications: `"The Window Switcher installation is broken, resources are missing"`.

I've checked the source code and know that it's because it is too old and doesn't work on new plasmas(uses 1.1 APIs instead of 2.0). I tried to switch to new versions of KDE APIs in qml, but none worked.

So it's pointless, trying to change the code without debug info. So how could I see detailed log of this notification error in KDE?

**P.S.** Arch Linux x86_64, 5.16.8-arch1-1, Plasma 5.24.0, KWin, Wayland.